# Application startup count and sent to website

Tags: c#, web, statistics

On a small test application, i want to make something that will count how many times the application has been started.
This counting, i would like to sent to an website address, where it will be counted +1 for each startup.

Now i was wondering, would such a thing even be possible in c# ?
And if so, anyone can help me point in the direction of what be best approach would be for something like this?

I already have been googling for this, but did not find anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use google analytics and the api for this?

Comment: Because i didn't had a clue that that would be posible :P so there is some way to use the analytics from goolgle ? that would be very nice. Do you maybe also know a tutorial page or something to set that up ?

Answer (score 1):

In the global.asax.cs you can do something like this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //make a call to save the +1
}
```

Comment: yea, but i wonder more about how to make such a call, and if that is possible

Comment: Yes, you can do any code you would normally do. Just write a separate service that persists your +1. How about a simple WCF service?

Comment: Im not yet deep into c# so i dont know how to set up such a thing, also i guess i need to do something at the website-side to log it there too.

Answer (score 0):

In the global asax file, there is a predefined event, Application_Start. You can put your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make that call from a Windows Application you can use the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("yourUrl");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

That will call `yourUrl` and you can track each call on the server side.

Comment: Yea i guess that is something im looking for. Now, i never have done this before and all i have is a website trough some hosting company. Got any idea what i need to to at the side of the website ? maybe you know some tutorial or something where they explain ?